# Controlling element CSS position with a custom jQuery scrollbar

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, position

would anyone please suggest a custom jQuery scrollbar that is able to easily control the CSS position of a desired element (ex: left, top) instead of the usual scrolling of an element with overflow: hidden? Practically: I have a far & wide position: absolute ol listing inside an overflow: hidden container and I need to control it's visible area by setting CSS position through a custom scrollbar.

Many thanks for the tips!

Comment: "to easily control the CSS position of a desired element (ex: left, top) instead of the usual scrolling of an element with overflow: hidden".  Instead? Usually you use the combination of both techniques.

Comment: Fair enough, I haven't really worked with custom scrollbars that much yet and wasn't sure on how they achieve the scrolling specifically. Any suggestions on a good base module to make this work that I can customize to achieve such behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see

### [jQuery.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and

### [jQuery.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) and

### [jQuery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

also read **[HERE](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/)**

Relative CSS

> We’ve ported the functionality from
> the .animate() method, giving you the
> ability to update CSS properties using
> relative values. You can now prefix a
> CSS value with “+=” or “-=” to update
> the property relatively, in relation
> to the current value.

```
// Move an item 10px over
$("#item").css("left", "+=10px");
```

Comment: Oh what a sweet jQuery update, exactly what I need to make this work easily. Thank you very much for the info.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a custom scrollbar, then you better use a ready-to-use plugin. Creating your own will probably take more time than you might think.

Here's a nice list of scrollbar plugins:

Comment: Seen this listing, quite a few nice finished scrollbars. I'll try using some to mount the desired functionality, thanks!